# Can't use Ubuntu Software Center or update Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, kubuntu, dpkg

I can't seem to be able to install anything with the Ubuntu Software Center or update my Ubuntu version.

When I run `sudo apt-get -f install` this is the output:

```
matt@Bessie:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
 kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 309 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/28.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package oxygen-icon-theme (--configure):
package oxygen-icon-theme is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kde-runtime:
kde-runtime depends on oxygen-icon-theme (>= 4:4.6); however:
 Package oxygen-icon-theme is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package kde-runtime (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qapt-batch:
 qapt-batch depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qapt-batch (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kubuntu-debug-installer:
 kubuntu-debug-installer depends on kde-runtime; however:
  Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.
 kubuntu-debug-installer depends on qapt-batch; however:
  Package qapt-batch is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kubuntu-debug-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                         No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a followup error from a previous failure.
                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of quassel:
quassel depends on kde-runtime; however:
 Package kde-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package quassel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 oxygen-icon-theme
 kde-runtime
 qapt-batch
 kubuntu-debug-installer
 quassel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't have much experience with this yet, so I don't know what is going on. I'm guessing it's probably errors it lists, but I'm not sure how to fix them.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your quoted error message, `oxygen-icon-theme` is "half-installed" and blocks the rest. Try the following:

```
sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove oxygen-icon-theme
```

This should fix your problem